# CO2 for duvel clone - Strong Golden Ale

Tags: fermentation, secondary-fermentation, brewing, ale, priming

What is the CO2 level for a Strong Golden Ale?

Each calculator have a different value:

1. 3.3 - [source](http://www.northernbrewer.com/learn/resources/priming-sugar-calculator/)
2. 2.5-3.2 - [source](http://www.brewunited.com/priming_sugar_calculator.php)
3. 1.9-2.4 - [source](http://www.tastybrew.com/calculators/priming.html)
4. 1.9 -2.4  [source](http://hbd.org/cgi-bin/recipator/recipator/carbonation.html)

It is correct if I use 160.36g of sucrose for 20 liters, 26ºc and 2.9 of CO2?

There is a risk of explode the bottle with this setup?

I read that a value higher than 8g/liter could explode, and 160.36/20 is 8.018.

Thanks

Comment: It would help to see a source for that claim, but *grams per liter* is a rather widely used measurement of CO2 in solution, much like volumes (for all intents and purposes 2 g/L = 1 volume CO2). It makes much more sense, then, that the danger of exceeding 8 g/L refers not to the amount of priming sugar used but rather to finished carbonation level (8 g/L, or ~ 4 vol., is way up there and could potentially result in bottle rupture).

Comment: @FranklinPCombs, I don't understand the conclusion. To be objective, what is the CO2 level that I should use?

Comment: Your suggestion of targeting 2.9 vol. (by using 160g sugar) seems perfectly fine. I was only commenting on your concerns about exploding bottles, where I think you were confusing g/L **sugar** used and g/L **CO2** in the finished beer.

Comment: @FranklinPCombs my fear is about bottles. The bottles that i have available have a thin glass. I will probably reduce the sugar to 140 or less. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I routinely use 150g of sucrose for 18-19 liter batches, and rarely have over carbonation. And then, only if I keep the beer in a warm place for a long time. No exploded bottles yet.

That being said, you should give the yeast plenty of time to flocculate before bottling, and don't open them when warm.

Comment: What is the beer style that you are talking (150g)?

Comment: Saison, usually 6-7% ABV. Sometimes I do  the same for a pale ale, sometimes reduce it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The calculators are someone's idea of what the style should be. Each brewery will do something different depending on tradition, marketing, and what they think their customers like.

You are your only customer. What do you like? High carbonation, or low carbonation?

I like low carbonation. I never do more than 2 volumes of CO2. For a 19L batch at room temperature, I'd use 64 grams of cane sugar, no more.